# td with white-space:nowrap text exceed outside of the cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, word-wrap

I'm trying to use nowrap on td properties so that the result can be seen on the first table:

[image: View]

As you can see, on the first table, it wrapped nicely.
But on the second table the first "td" exceeding it's second "td" because the content is too long.
How do I fix this?
Here's my code:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="content" style="width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; max-width:300px">
            /*php content*/
        </td>
        <td class="author">
            /*php content*/
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To make it more clear, here's what I'm trying to do:
At first I created a list which each element is a table, here's what each of the list code:

```
<div class="post">
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="content" style="max-width:300px">
        /* php content */
        </td>
        <td class="author">
            /* php content */
        </td;>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="nav">
        /* php content for navigation buttons */
</div>
```

But the result is like this:
[image]

As you can see on the first list, there are white spaces between "test 1" and the "admin todo" status.
I want to remove it, therefore I use the nowrap method. If this impossible, is there any alternative method?

Comment: think setting styles to `td` tags is quite limited, have you tried wrapping the text in a `div` or `span` and style that?

Comment: didn't you actually mean `normal` instead of `nowrap`?

Comment: `nowrap` is going to prevent the `td` from breaking to the next line, so this is pretty much the opposite of what you want, no?

Comment: @webeno Tried it, but if I use div or span, the second content will be placed on the second line/row from the first content.
I want the two contents to be in one line/row.

Comment: so if you don't want it to wrap, what do you want the long text to do instead?

Comment: @jmore009 If I don't use nowrap, the result will be like this:http://i.imgur.com/Y5haDv2.jpg I want to remove the white spaces, so I use nowrap, is there another method?

Comment: @webeno I want the long text to be wrapped just like normal paragraph, but I want to remove the whitespace just like what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: sorry, it's not very clear: could you please create a mock-up of how you'd like it to look like?

Comment: think you're using the wrong css property... if I was you, i'd just get rid of the 2nd td, add some space after the text with padding or something, and stick it after inside a `span` tag for example...

Comment: @webeno But what if the first content is more than 1 line? I want the second content's place is fixed on the first line.

Comment: just forget "white-space" it's not what you need... try with setting the width of the 2nd td to something fixed, and do not set any with on the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpretate correctly the question and understand your expected results i suggest you tu use `text-overflow`

Since you stated 300px as width of `td.content` and still want the content to be rendered in one line only, I guess the only solution is to hide the exceding content. It can be done with this simple CSS:

```
.content{
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```